# How to create a 2D ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to use Java to create a 2-dimensional array. The size of rows is known, while the size of columns is unknown. Here is my code and it doesn't work. Could anyone give me some idea?

```
ArrayList<Integer> paths[];
paths = new ArrayList[2]；// 2 paths
for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    paths[i].add(1); // add an element to each path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the array element before adding to it. Put the initialization into the `for` loop:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Integer>[] paths = new ArrayList[2];

for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
    paths[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    paths[i].add(1);
}
```

This way you can avoid the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I got a error saying "cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<Integer>" for the 1st line.

Comment: What editor do you use? What java version? In my Eclipse it is only a warning, and compiles and runs perfectly (I use 1.7 compiler with 1.6 source code level). I also set `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, it does not even warn.

Comment: I use eclipse and the JDK7u10

Comment: Thanks GaborSch, I got it! But how to set the warning to be "unchecked"? Why ArrayList<Integer>[] paths = new ArrayList[2] not ArrayList<Integer>[] paths = new ArrayList<Integer>[2]?

Comment: Updated the answer. Press `Ctrl-1` in Eclipse and select from the options. The other "magic" is `Ctrl-Space`. Use them everywhere, there are million suggestions!

Comment: @user2570387 Lazier way: Put your mouse on the warned tokens and the options will show.

Comment: Just found it. Thanks!

Comment: If you put `<Integer>`, you will get `Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<Integer>` error.

Comment: @johnchen902 I'm a keyboard-fan, but it's good to know. I simply can't wait until the popup shows :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a "2d" `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<>();
```

And here is the non-diamond operator version for Java < 1.7:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to 
  ArrayList<List<Integer>>

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>[]

Comment: @user2570387 the line I posted doesn't try to convert to `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>[] `, it creates an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists` of `Integer`

Comment: "'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7" - most likely OP has something lower that 1.7, so probably this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend this

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
            paths.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```