# Java : differnce between arraylist and general array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am bit confused in general array `Array[10][10]` and ArrayList `ArrayList[10][10]`

ArrayList is if an elements are added to an `ArrayList`, its capacity grows automatically.
if in `ArrayList` we have defined `ArrayList[10][10]` then is this not a fixed size of ArrayList ?

then What is the difference between a general `Array` and `Arraylist` at this stage.

Query from here

[How to create an 2D ArrayList in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956720/how-to-create-an-2d-arraylist-in-java?lq=1)

[How to create a 2D ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689258/how-to-create-a-2d-arraylist?rq=1)

**Updated question:**
If i want to store many account numbers and their amount then how can i do this with `ArrayList`.

Previosuly with general array i have did this with **`Array[10][2]`**..in this here was 10 index and 2 value (Account number and their amount) ..
But with **`ArrayList`** how ?

Comment: (That's not a valid way to access an ArrayList.)

Comment: It seems that you are confusing *ArrayList* with *array of ArrayLists*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in structure which could dynamically grow in size and let you map one value into another (like accountNumber -> amount) then you may be interested in `Map`. You could use for instance

```
Map<int,double> map = new HashMap<int,double>();
```

where `int` is type we use as key - account number, and `double` is value which will be connected with key (in reality `double` is not best type to store informations about amount of money, you would probably use something like `BigDecimal`, but for now lets leave `double`).

To `put` informations about account and its amount to map just use

```
map.put(1, 42);
```

which would bound key `1` with value `42`.

To update amount stored in account with number 1 and lets say add 3 dollars just `get` current amount from account number you are interested in, calculate new value and put it in map like

```
map.put(1, map.get(1)+3);
```

---

In case you really must use Lists you can try to use advantage of fact that Java is object oriented language. Create your ow class which will represent account. Such class should have `number` and `amount` fields. It can look like

```
class Account {
    // fields representing state of Account
    private int number;
    private double amount; //again in real world double would not be best choice
                           //and you would use something like BigDecimal

    // getters and setters
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    // constructor
    public Account(int number, double amount) {
        this.number = number;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

and create list of instances of such class. You can create such list with

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

Notice that used `List` as type of reference `List<Account> accounts` not `ArrayList<Account> accounts` because generally it is better to [program on interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

To add new accounts to such list just use `add` method like

```
accounts.add(new Account(1, 42));
accounts.add(new Account(2, 200));
accounts.add(new Account(3, 60));
```

which will add new Account instances. Notice that with this approach nothing stops you from creating few instances of Account class representing same account number which would be impossible with mentioned earlier Map approach (each key in Map can hold only one value and using `put` with already used key will replace old value with new one).

Comment: thankyou very much .. it will really help ful for me.. i appriciate

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList[10][10`] is a two dimensional array of `ArrayList` objects.
`Array[][]` is the same, but with Array instances.
The same way you can define `Integer[][]`! This doesn't make Array the same as `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

always 2D array should be represented using list of list and thats the best way of using list in java rather that with the above syntax.

code snippet

```
int x[][] = new int[10][10];
```

should be represented as

```
        List l = new ArrayList();
        List ll = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            ll.add(l);
        }



 here x[0] gives array and ll.get(0) gives list 

x[0][0] gives first element from first 1D array and

ll.get(0).get(0) gives the first element from first list
```